# urllib.urlretrieve makes GUI window not respond

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, download

I'm making a game using Panda3D, and I'm currently making a downloader to download the latest update. If you don't know what Panda3D is, just imagine the GUI I'm talking about as a Tkinter window :P. The functions I use are:

```
def doDownload():
    urllib.urlretrieve("http://hiddenfile/hi.txt", "hi.txt", reporthook=report)

def report(count, blockSize, totalSize):
    percent = int(count*blockSize*100/totalSize)
    gui.downloadBar['value'] = percent
```

However, this makes the GUI window not respond, yet the console window is fine. If it doesn't respond, users will think it's stuck and end its process, and their gamedata will be corrupted. I've tried running on seperate threads, like this:

```
def doDownload():
    threading.Thread(target=__doDownload).start()

def __doDownload():
    urllib.urlretrieve("http://hiddenfile/hi.txt", "hi.txt", reporthook=report)

def report(count, blockSize, totalSize):
    percent = int(count*blockSize*100/totalSize)
    gui.downloadBar['value'] = percent
```

But that doesn't even download it. Is there any way to download a file, without a window (ex. Tkinter window) going unresponsive?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with using a separate thread for I/O. It's probably not working because you need to update the UI from the main thread. Try changing `report()` to save that information in a structure that can be checked later by the UI thread.

Comment: It doesn't download when on a seperate thread. I tried adding `print(progress)` into the report function, and it didn't even print. Not to mention that it didn't even download the file, because I couldn't see it in the folder I was running it in, even after the download process had started.

Comment: When I run your second snippet in an interpreter and call doDownload(), it runs and downloads. Sorry, I don't know much about your environment. Perhaps a full, runnable example that produces your threading issue will help get some answers.